# Does spring native support spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch dependency?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I am trying to build a spring native image with ‘spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch’ dependency which uses RestHighLevelClient to interact with elasticsearch.

It turns out I always receive ‘connection refused’ exception. Any idea why this happens?

Note: My application is deployed in AWS Lambda.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may be firewall configuration, **connection refused** means nothing is listening the port you are trying to connect. good thing you can reach the IP.

Comment: did you try to deploy it in jvm mode first?